# ELMAH setup - errors not being caught

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I've setup ELMAH exactly as with the sample app. I attempt to throw an error to test ELMAH by using:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

Unfortunately however my app is going straight to the error and ELMAH is not catching/logging the error. I am using ASP.NET 3.5. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as the Web.Config is exactly the same as the sample

Comment: @DKong: I revised my post a bit, let me know if that helps you at all...

Comment: Do you see the InvalidOperationException YSOD related to your code above? Or is it a different exception?

Comment: can you post your web.config? (obviously remove any private information)

Answer (score 5):

Double check your Web.config.  I had the same problem until I realized I forgot to register the module.

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
```

I found this article over on [dotnetslackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx) helpful.

Comment: i've got that line, but still no joy.

Comment: Doh, I was missing this line.  It was particularly vexing because it worked in dev, but I'm on IIS 7 in dev, IIS 6 in prod...I wonder why I didn't need it in IIS?  Either way, thanks, this was exactly it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Elmah is open source, you should add the code as a project in your solution and make sure that you have visual studio break on all exceptions.  It sounds feasible that Elmah is throwing an Exception which would be swallowed.  This exact thing was happening with me and it was a permission on the stored procedure that inserts the error.

**ORIGINAL**
Is your test within a try/catch block?  If so, you'll have to explicitly force the logging to occur.

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

**MY WEB.CONFIG SETUP**

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
   ...
   </configSections>

  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="TESTElmahConnectionString" />
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
  </elmah>


<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: no try catch block yet. i am just looking to get the basic default handling working before i try signaling